# How to use the "var[].function()" caller dispatch?

Tags: python, dictionary, dispatch

I am trying to learn how to dispatch an action that is related to an element of a dictionary.

I´ve seen a lot of times the formula `dictionary[element].function()`, and there the function calls the `element` of the dictionary.

I am trying to do that with this code, but I can not get the working method.

Any ideas?

(The last line of the code is the syntax that I want to use)

Thank you in advance!

```
def function(arg):
    print 'Running ' + str(arg)

data={}
data[0]={'name':'Ruben', 'run':function}
data[1]={'name':'David', 'run':function}

print data
data[0].run()
```

Comment: Did you mean `data[0]['run']()`? You can't access values using the key like an attribute in vanilla Python dictionaries, and a dictionary doesn't have a callable attribute named `run`.

Comment: Hello jonsharpe, yes, I mean that. But I´ve seen that a lot of times (in the format of the last line of the code) and I will like to learn how to do it.

Comment: Then you need to put the correct thing into the `data` dictionary, i.e. some object with a callable `run` attribute.

Comment: @RubenMedrano That isn't what a dictionary is for.  It may be [classes](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html) that you are interested in.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't mixing up Python and some other language? Javascript, perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

Use `data[0]['run']('Hello World!')`. This executes the function with the argument `Hello World!` and prints:

```
Running Hello World!
```